# Can't manipulate Label from JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to change the text of a JavaFX software GUI label every time the user goes to that page. For that, I must be able to change the values of that label, such as parse it to a variable and do these stuff.

Problem is, since the label is all written in FXML, I don't know how to use it properly on Java. I tried:

@FXML public Label WordID;

in order to make the label (which has "WordID" as an ID) an object, but I've failed. When I do that, the program simply won't go to that frame anymore. What do I do?

Code:

```
public class Screen3Controller implements Initializable, ControlledScreen {

ScreensController myController;

  @Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}

public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent){
    myController = screenParent;
}

@FXML
private void goToScreen1(ActionEvent event){
   myController.setScreen(ScreensFramework.screen1ID);
}

@FXML
private void goToScreen2(ActionEvent event){
   myController.setScreen(ScreensFramework.screen2ID);
}

}
```

FXML:

```
<Label fx:id="WordID" layoutX="393.0" layoutY="148.0" prefWidth="177.0" text="">
  <font>
    <Font name="Avenir Roman" size="40.0" />
  </font>
</Label>
```

Button Listener from Screen2:

```
@FXML
private void goToScreen3(ActionEvent event){
   myController.setScreen(ScreensFramework.screen3ID);
   WordID.setText("LOl");
}
```

Error message:

> Glass detected outstanding Java exception at -[GlassViewDelegate     sendJavaMouseEvent:]:src/com/sun/mat/ui/GlassViewDelegate.m:543
>   Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>   ...
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1444)
>       ... 40 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at screensframework.Screen3Controller.mostrarPalavra(Screen3Controller.java:89)
>       ... 50 more

Comment: `WordID` or `palavraID`?

Comment: wordID. I've changed it to make it more readable on StackOverflow but forgot to change on the FXML. Anyways, it still won't work after I change it

Comment: What do you want to write in the Label? What event will trigger this up?

Comment: I'm making a sort of a questionary. Everytime someone goes to the next frame of the program, it must switch the question (which is the label I wanna change). The event that will trigger this up is the switching from one frame to another, which comes after a button click.

Answer (score 1):

To work with the `Label` programmatically all you need to do is to declare a variable in the `Controller` file with the same id as it is declared in your `.fxml` file:

**YourFXML.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="com.sample.Screen3Controller ">
    ...
    <Label fx:id="WordID" layoutX="393.0" layoutY="148.0" prefWidth="177.0" text="">
      <font>
        <Font name="Avenir Roman" size="40.0" />
      </font>
    </Label>
    ...
</AnchorPane>
```

`com.sample.Screen3Controller` must reference an existing `.java` file in the `com.sample` package.

**Screen3Controller .java**

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;  //make sure you're importing the JavaFX Label

public class Screen3Controller implements Initializable, ControlledScreen {

    ScreensController myController;
    @FXML private Label WordID;

    ...

    WordID.setText("some text...");

    ...
}
```

Comment: It still won't work. When I do it, the next frame simply doesn't open when I click the action button. What could be possibly happening with my program?

Comment: What exactly are you calling `frame`? You don't need a new Scene, just redefine the values in the current one. Can you add the Button's listener to your question?

Comment: I'm calling frame a _scene_. I'll add the Button's listener to the question. Btw, if you have a tutorial who's gonna help me with these JavaFX issues, I'll be eternally grateful.

Comment: @user3088010 I can recommend you a great tutorial that I followed myself which leaded me through a situation similar to yours, [here is the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GsdaZWDcdY) and [here is the website](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1)

Comment: Third following day and I still can't solve this! I found out that this error only appears when I have multiple scenes, like the one from the video you showed me. I did exactly that way, and when I try to change the value of the label on an action (such as clicking a button), the following error message appears on the console (I added it to the question at the top). I need to finish this till tomorrow and I'm totally desperate! HELP

Comment: @user3088010 You are having a `NullPointerException` at `Screen3Controller.java` line 89. Is there where `WordID.setText("LOl");` lies? If so, please: Click on your Java project in the Package Explorer in eclipse and press F5, it will update to the last `.fxml` you have. You might be editing the `.fxml` but the Eclipse don't see the newest version. It is a guess.